# How can use date format with time zone from 8 AM to 8 AM data download?

Tags: google-earth-engine

How can use date format with time zone from 8 AM to 8 AM data download ?

```
var inidate = ee.Date.fromYMD(2020,03,17)
var enddate = ee.Date.fromYMD(2020,03,18)
```

`enter code here`[enter link here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/ad6e3a90ff9d79d4726a0ae48984411f)

Comment: Sorry, I am not able to understand what you are trying to do... Can you please explain a bit more?

Comment: I want to dawnlod rainfall data from 8 am to nextday 8 am how can use data format to dawnlod data 24 hr ( for ex : 2020/03/17 : 8am to 2020/3/18 : 8 am )

Answer (score 1):

You could use client-side Dates to generate `initdate` and `enddate` in millis, and filter on `system:time_start`:

```
var initdate = new Date('2020-03-16').setUTCHours(8)
var enddate = new Date('2020-03-17').setUTCHours(7) // 7 to exclude 8 for next day maybe?

var gsmap = ee.ImageCollection('JAXA/GPM_L3/GSMaP/v6/operational')
  .filter(ee.Filter.rangeContains('system:time_start', initdate, enddate))
  .select('hourlyPrecipRate');
```

Comment: thanks for your answer , but i get error when i run the code ( enddate.difference is not a function)

Comment: You haven't shared your assets, so I haven't been able to run your code. You use inidate and enddate for other things, so maybe something like this would be better (again, I cannot run the script, so I'm not 100% this is correct): https://code.earthengine.google.com/3dc0592771f79e8251ff1b5084a71ad1

Comment: In your script, initdate and enddate were ee.Date instances, I turned them into longs (which don't have a difference() function). The link in my last comment keeps initdate and enddate as ee.Date but do the image filtering using long timestamps.

Comment: sorry brother i don't know how can solve this error